# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/xml

Tags: apache, http, google-chrome, cxf, mime-types

I have some RESTful APIs that I am building using Apache CXF. I was using the browser to test my results and this works fine mostly. 
However, in some cases I get "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/xm" error on Chrome and with firefox I get "XML Parsing Error: no element found"

The strange thing is that if I restrict my response by adding some conditions then it works fine. This makes me thing its related to the size of response. I have searched the web but I didn't find any concrete answers.

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Apache Camel to route my requests to different services. I had the streamCache flag enabled for my CamelContext configuration. Disabling the streamCaching resolved the issue.

Details about stream caching can found at the following url:
http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html